# CDK toolbar does not appear on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor

I'm new to Drupal and I'm using version 7.  The CDKeditor is listed as v7.x-1.17.

When I edit a page the CDK toolbar is suddenly not appearing.  The only thing I see are red diagnoal lines and a tiny arrow on the right that says "Insert Paragraph Here."

Does anyone know how to get the CDK toolbar to pop up again?  I'm on a Mac.

Thank you very much for any help!

Polina

I tried looking at the CDKEditor tool bar configuration and adding some icons to the existing toolbar.  I click save and got "your tooldbar has been updated."  Maybe this is what made the toolbar completely disappear?

Comment: I think you mean the "CKEditor" not the "CDKEditor". Drupal uses CKEditor https://ckeditor.com/ Drupal does not use, or have any relation to the AWS Cloud Development Kit (AWS CDK) https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/ I've updated the tags on your question accordingly.